# Best way of confirming system clock of controller

Tags: pic, clock-speed

I would like to know the tricks or hints which could be used to find the system clock of 8   bit micro controllers.
What are the cool ways in which we could find the system clock and can be verified with documents.

I have heard of toggling a pin continuously but i don't know the specifics.It would be helpful if you could share your way of doing things to find system clock.

It would be helpful if you could list the common tricks to verify the clock other than reading data sheet.
If i could determine that by toggling an i/o pin continuously.What data is obtained from the observed frequency?.It would vary depending up on asm or c compiler i trust.

Please do enlighten me

Im using pic18f26j50

Regards

Answer (score 7):

You don't specify a family as such, but you have tagged it "PIC".

The PIC microcontrollers all have the ability, when using either an external clock module or the internal oscillator, to feed the clock signal to a specific pin (OSC2), both for confirming the clock, and for driving external devices.

Comment: What could be done for toggling an i/o pin and finding those in a scope.What is the calculation behind that method.

Comment: Majenko gave you an excellent answer and you ignored it. You don't need to toggle an I/O pin. The PIC will literally output a square wave with the same frequency as the system clock. You just need to configure the oscillator settings to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Toggling an i/o pin won't give you what you need if the toggling happens using a loop. A jump operation takes time and, depending on the architecture, it may or may not drop the execution of one or two ASM commands following the jump command.

It is better if the code is inlined. Only use ASM since you don't know what the assembler might do.

The following is valid for an ATMEL AT8515 but you should be able to translate it to any architecture.

```
.INCLUDE "8515def.inc"
.ORG 0X0000
RJMP RESET

RESET:

LDI R16, HIGH(RAMEND)   ; Stack init
OUT SPH, R16
LDI R16, LOW(RAMEND)
OUT SPH, R16

LDI R16,0XFF        ;PORTB for output
OUT DDRB, R16
OUT PORTB, R16

LDI R21, 0X01       ; bit 0 is high
LDI R20, 0X00       ; bit 0 is low

                    ; copy paste the following two lines as many times as desired
OUT PORTB, R21      ; set PORTB, bit 0 high
OUT PORTB, R20      ; set PORTB, bit 0 low

OUT PORTB, R21
OUT PORTB, R20

OUT PORTB, R21
OUT PORTB, R20
```

Don't forget to check how many clock cycles it takes for the OUT command to execute and the new value to appear at the output.

However, you are better off using a PWM or counter peripheral of the μC and configure it so it counts up to 1 and then resets.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a periodic interrupt and use that for system timing- for example you might generate an interrupt every 1ms. If you count that down by 500 and toggle a pin every 500ms you'll get a 1Hz "heartbeat" indication that a human (or dog, for that matter) can see by looking at an LED.

There will typically be a bit of jitter in it due to latency of the ISR etc, but some micros support a pin change on interrupt so you can preset it (at 499 interrupts from the last toggle) to toggle the pin exactly on the next interrupt so there is nanosecond-level jitter even in a 500ms pulse width.

Answer (score 1):

Using the pin toggling method you would look at the compiler output to see exactly which instructions are being used for the while(1) loop which is doing the pin toggling. Next you would have to know how many clock cycles each one of those instructions take. After converting the instructions to the number of clock cycles, look at the scope and get the half period of the square wave. This will correspond to one loop (the whole period involves two loops). When you divide half period by the number of clock cycles required to perform one loop, you fill find the period of a single cycle. The inverse of it will be your frequency.